Pine Script: Automatically mark point in previous day
Hi i have a script that automatically draw open price of 00:00 and 08:30 candles. The problem is the code only mark for current day, not for historical data. Can anyone help me modify the code so that it can also mark these point in previous day. Thank you in advance
//@version=5
indicator("Daily Open Price Markers", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2880)

// Define timezone as New York time
time_zone = "America/New_York"

// Variables to store open prices and timestamps
var float open_0000 = na
var float open_0830 = na
var int time_0000 = na
var int time_0830 = na
var int time_1100 = na

// Function to get the time of 11:00 AM New York time
f_get_1100_time() =>
    // Search for the 11:00 AM New York time bar within the last 720 bars
    var int eleven_am_time = na
    for i = 0 to 719
        if (hour(time[i], time_zone) == 11 and minute(time[i], time_zone) == 0)
            eleven_am_time := time[i]
            break
    eleven_am_time

// Loop through bars to find and mark the open prices of 00:00 AM and 08:30 AM candles
if (bar_index > 0)
    current_day = dayofmonth(time[0], time_zone)
    
    // Find and set open and timestamp for 00:00 AM New York time candle
    if (hour(time, time_zone) == 0 and minute(time, time_zone) == 0)
        open_0000 := open
        time_0000 := time
    
    // Find and set open and timestamp for 08:30 AM New York time candle
    if (hour(time, time_zone) == 8 and minute(time, time_zone) == 30)
        open_0830 := open
        time_0830 := time
    
    // Get the 11:00 AM New York time
    time_1100 = f_get_1100_time()
    
    // Draw lines if we have all necessary times
    if not na(open_0000) and not na(time_0000) and not na(time_1100)
        line.new(x1=time_0000, y1=open_0000, x2=time_1100, y2=open_0000, color=color.red, width=1, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    
    if not na(open_0830) and not na(time_0830) and not na(time_1100)
        line.new(x1=time_0830, y1=open_0830, x2=time_1100, y2=open_0830, color=color.blue, width=1, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

This is what I get from the above code. The black line represent the day seperator
text
